# Can I stop a modal pop up using validation on the main view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, bootstrap-modal

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC app. This is the login view with a modal section that pops up and lets you submit a password reset. I have now deployed to it to my test box and it appears to run validation on the login form when I try to reset the password. I put an email address into the reset popup, I hit submit but the login page in the background gets the 'This field is required' validation alerts on the two input boxes. If i fill them in can actually get passed it and submit the reset password request. Is there a way to get around this?

```
<div class="login-body">
<div class="container">
    <form method="post" class="form-signin" action="/Account/Login?returnurl=%2F">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign In</h2>
        <div class="login-wrap">
            <div class="user-login-info">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" autofocus data-val="true" data-val-email="Please, provide a valid email address." data-val-required="This field is required." id="Email" name="Email" value="" />
                <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" data-val="true" data-val-required="This field is required." id="Password" name="Password" />
                <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>

            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Remember me? field is required." id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" value="true" /> Remember me
                <span class="pull-right">
                    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#forgotPassModal">Reset Password</a>
                </span>
            </label>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-login btn-block" type="submit">Sign In</button>

            <div class="registration">
                Don't have an account yet?
                <a href="/Account/Register">Create an account</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal -->

    <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="forgotPassModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Reset Password</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Enter your e-mail address below to reset your password.</p>
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix">

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Cancel</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-success" method="post" formaction="/Account/ForgotPassword">Submit</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should use two forms, one for the login form, second for the password reset form.

Comment: So two different views? Or can i still use a second form in the popup?

Comment: You can use multiple forms in the same view, a password reset form and a normal login form.